# while running the installation command to install magento2.4.5 it say "Search engine 'elasticsearch7. is not an available search engine."

Tags: elasticsearch, magento, magento2, elasticsearch-7, magento2.4

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Juub.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhGTq.png)
Elasticsearch is already running but still shows this error

Comment: WHat's the URL you use to get the response in the second image?

Comment: I have used this url: localhost:9200

Comment: http or https? and how is Magento configured?

Comment: Magento was configured with http